# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, search

laravel join tabel search.

error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `tbl_die_management_categories`.*, `tbl_die_management_subcategories`.`id` as `t2`, `tbl_die_management_subcategories`.`die_weight` from `tbl_die_management_categories` inner join `tbl_die_management_subcategories` on `tbl_die_management_categories`.`id` = `tbl_die_management_subcategories`.`die_categories_id` where `created_at` like %2022-11-17%)

```
 public function diemanagement(Request $request)
    {
        $DieManagementCategories = DB::table('tbl_die_management_categories');
        if($request->keyword != null){
           $DieManagementCategories = $DieManagementCategories->where('created_at','like','%'.$request->keyword.'%');
        }
        $DieManagementCategories = $DieManagementCategories->select('tbl_die_management_categories.*','tbl_die_management_subcategories.id as t2','tbl_die_management_subcategories.die_weight')
        ->join('tbl_die_management_subcategories','tbl_die_management_categories.id','=','tbl_die_management_subcategories.die_categories_id')
        ->get();
        // dd(json_encode($DieManagementCategories));
        $DieManagementCategories = DieManagementCategories::with('subcategories')->get();
  
        return view('admin.diemanagement.diemanagement',['DieManagementCategories'=>$DieManagementCategories]);
        
    }
```

Comment: try this $DieManagementCategories->where('created_at', $request->keyword);

Answer (score 3):

you have two tables to select from in your query

```
tbl_die_management_categories, tbl_die_management_subcategories
```

both with `created_at` column...
in your `where` clause you should specify on what `created_at` column the condition will be applied ....
just set the table name before column name to do that:

```
 if($request->keyword != null){
           $DieManagementCategories = $DieManagementCategories->where('tbl_die_management_categories.created_at','like','%'.$request->keyword.'%');
        }
```